# Run multiple Teamviewer instances at the same time

Tags: 14.04, server, remote-desktop, teamviewer, multi-user

I'm using `Teamviewer` 11 in order to remotely connect to `Ubuntu Server` 14.04. I want that each Ubuntu's user will be able to simultaneously remotely connect to this server with `Teamviewer`.

Currently, `Teamviewer` generates the same `Partner ID` for all `Ubuntu`'s users. Is it possible that each `Ubuntu`'s user will have his own `Partner ID` in `Teamviewer` and will be able to remotely connect to the server without disturbing other users' remote session?

Comment: That you will need to ask teamviewer... It is a 3rd party app using closed software. You probably need a business license.

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer won't do that. What you need is something like NoMachine, such as the Workstation or Terminal Server. I.e you want to create multiple Linux instances on one machine and each user connects to their own instance without interfering with the others running there